# Removing elements in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML, I need to check the whole XML file and remove any Record_Number with the same Date, Action and Reason.

```
<Data>
<Row>
    <Record>
        <Record_Row>
            <Record_Number>111</Record_Number>
            <Date>10242016</Date>
            <Action>RFL</Action>
            <Reason>RFL</Reason>
        </Record_Row>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Record_Row>
            <Record_Number>111</Record_Number>
            <Date>10242016</Date>
            <Action>RFL</Action>
            <Reason>RFL</Reason>
        </Record_Row>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Record_Row>
            <Record_Number>111</Record_Number>
            <Date>06302016</Date>
            <Action>TER</Action>
            <Reason>ATT</Reason>
        </Record_Row>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Record_Row>
            <Record_Number>444</Record_Number>
            <Date>04012016</Date>
            <Action>HIR</Action>
            <Reason>REH</Reason>
        </Record_Row>
    </Record>
</Row>
</Data>
```

So in the example above, only **one** Record_Number 111 with Date 10242016
and Action RFL and Reason RFL should remain.

Note that there might be 3 or more elements with the same Date, Action and Reason referencing to a single Record_Number, but in my example above I have only used 2.

It should give me this xml file after applying the logic:

```
<Data>
<Row>
    <Record>
        <Record_Row>
            <Record_Number>111</Record_Number>
            <Date>10242016</Date>
            <Action>RFL</Action>
            <Reason>RFL</Reason>
        </Record_Row>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Record_Row>
            <Record_Number>111</Record_Number>
            <Date>06302016</Date>
            <Action>TER</Action>
            <Reason>ATT</Reason>
        </Record_Row>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Record_Row>
            <Record_Number>444</Record_Number>
            <Date>04012016</Date>
            <Action>HIR</Action>
            <Reason>REH</Reason>
        </Record_Row>
    </Record>
</Row>
</Data>
```

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. Please check out other answers. Depending on the XSLT version you are using, you may want to read Muenchian Grouping(XSLT1.0) or `<xsl:for-each-group>` (XSLT2.0).

Comment: Also, please post the XSLT code you have written till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Muenchian Grouping in **XSLT-1.0:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:key name="record-row-key" match="Data/Row/Record/Record_Row" use="concat(Record_Number,Date,Action,Reason)"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="Data/Row/Record">
        <xsl:for-each select="Record_Row[generate-id()=generate-id(key('record-row-key',concat(Record_Number,Date,Action,Reason)[1]))]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using `<for-each-group>` in **XSLT-2.0:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Data>
            <Row>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="Data/Row/Record" group-by="concat(Record_Row/Record_Number,Record_Row/Date,Record_Row/Action,Record_Row/Reason)">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </Row>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```